# ofstream.put(); not writing ints?

Tags: c++, file-io, output

I'm trying to encrypt a file in a very simple manner. Converting the text `aabcdee` to `a2bcde2` for example.

However, when I execute the file, I get `a^Cbcde^C` in the output file instead of `a2bcde2`.

I'm guessing `ofstream.put();` does not write integers to a file?  How do I go about doing this the right way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;
    char kar;
    input.open ("file.txt", ios::in);
    if ( ! input)
    {
        cout << "File not opened!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    output.open ("output.txt", ios::out);
    char prevkar = '\n';
    kar = input.get ();
    int rep = 1;
    
    while ( ! input.eof () )
    {
        if (kar == prevkar)
        {
           rep++;
           kar = input.get();

        }
        else
        { 
           if (rep > 1)
           {
               output.put(rep);
           }
            output.put (kar);
            prevkar = kar;
            kar = input.get ();
        }
    }
    input.close ();
    output.close ();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you use hex viewer? Is ^C displayed on console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
output.put(rep);
```

You are outputting `rep` as a character.  So whatever character that has the integer value of `rep` is what is being displayed.  In this case that is `^C`.  If you want to output the the actual value of `rep` then you should use `>>`

```
output >> rep;
```

You could also use

```
output.put('0' + rep);
```

This will only work to output 0-9